# How to transform subsequent row values based on previous row value, inside groups?

Tags: r, dplyr, panel-data

I am new to R and data programming in general. Please excuse any eventual confusion in this explanation.

I am working on a database that tracks units across years. These participate or not in a program. 1 denotes participation, and 0, otherwise.

I would like to add a column for which participation status remains as treated after its first treated year, independently of when treatment initiated. Basically: once treated, always treated.

Example:

lets say I have a df as such:

```
units <- c("A1","A1","A1","A1","A2","A2","A2","A2","A3","A3","A3","A3")
years <- c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993)
treated <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
df <- data.frame(units,years,treated)
```

So the df looks like:

```
   units years treated
1  A1    1990  0
2  A1    1991  1
3  A1    1992  1
4  A1    1993  1
5  A2    1990  0
6  A2    1991  1
7  A2    1992  0
8  A2    1993  0
9  A3    1990  0
10 A3    1991  0
11 A3    1992  0
12 A3    1993  1
```

Units A1 and A3 are fine. My problem is with unit A2. I would like to create a new column in which the years following 1991 produce value '1' as well.

My desired output would be as such:

```
   units years treated treated2
1  A1    1990  0       0
2  A1    1991  1       1
3  A1    1992  1       1
4  A1    1993  1       1
5  A2    1990  0       0
6  A2    1991  1       1
7  A2    1992  0       1
8  A2    1993  0       1
9  A3    1990  0       0
10 A3    1991  0       0
11 A3    1992  0       0
12 A3    1993  1       1
```

This example is simplified. My original db has thousands of units tracked for 15 years.

I have tried using dplyr functions as 'group_by' and 'if_else', but I haven't yet achieved satisfying results.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `cummax` after grouping by 'units'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(units) %>%
   mutate(treated2 = cummax(treated)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
#   units years treated treated2
#   <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 A1     1990       0        0
# 2 A1     1991       1        1
# 3 A1     1992       1        1
# 4 A1     1993       1        1
# 5 A2     1990       0        0
# 6 A2     1991       1        1
# 7 A2     1992       0        1
# 8 A2     1993       0        1
# 9 A3     1990       0        0
#10 A3     1991       0        0
#11 A3     1992       0        0
#12 A3     1993       1        1
```